# How to avoid double & dotted/dashed lines unexpectedly joins the segments?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

As you can notice, the dots of the dotted double line are joined by two very thin lines. Also the dashed-double line joins them automatically. Is there a way out to remove those unions? (I left `knots` there because I'd like this solution to be compatible with that package).

This is a zoom to the (relevant) issue of the following code:
 [image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \clip (-4,1) rectangle (1,7); 
\begin{knot}[
 clip width=5 ,
 scale =3,
 clip radius=8pt,
 line  cap=butt, 
 ]
\strand [dotted,double, double distance=2pt]   (-1 ,1)
to  [out=up ,  in=down ]  (0 ,2) ; 

 \end{knot}

 \begin{knot}[
 clip width=5 ,
 scale =3,
 clip radius=8pt,
 ]
\strand [red,dashed,double, double distance=2pt] (0,1.5)
to  [out=up , in=down ]  (-1 ,1);
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a rendering problem. There is not much you can do about it other than removing the antialiasing in adobe reader.

Comment: Ok, I don't have acrobat reader; it's no longer there for Linux... but thanks. I guess I'll draw a white line in between.

Comment: That's basically the best solution there is, I believe. You can get acroread for Linux, still. It is just an older version. Also, it is a pain since it is extremely slow especially on starting up. Horrible.

Comment: Define something like `double dotted/.style={preaction={dotted},postaction={white}}`. Same trick applies if you want triple dotted with phases.