# Ghostly lines in tiled clipped pics

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I am trying to tile two clipped `pic` elements like this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  one/.pic = {
    \path[clip] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
    \draw [double=white, draw=black, line cap = rect] (1,0) -- (0.6,0.6); 
    }
  }
\path pic {one} pic[rotate=90,yscale=-1] {one};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am seeing ghostly lines, both at the borders of the pics and where they adjoin.

[image]
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is an unfortunate feature of `double`, which does not really draw a double line, but a thick line overlaid with a thiner white line in the middle. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262756 for a related question. AFAIK there is no really simple working solution, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I tried extending the double lines, but got the same ghost lines, so it seems more of a bug than a feature. Rolling your own double lines seems a reasonable solution (until someone fixes the "feature").

Comment: I think that the real fix would be to have a function in the graphics drivers that draws true double lines. It may very well exist already, I do not know very much on these things. Anyway, drawing two individual lines has the additional benefit that it does not overpaint things in the back in white, which `double` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unfortunate feature of `double`, which does not really draw a double line, but a thick line overlaid with a thinner white line in the middle. There have been many related questions such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262756). Assuming that you do not want to fiddle around with the viewer settings, you could draw the double lines as true double lines using `calc`. The proposal here draws the double for a single straight stretch, so it is not a true generalization of `double`. And since you clip anyway you could extend the line in both directions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  real double straight line/.style={to path={
  ($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) -- 
    ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
  ($(\tikztostart)!#1!-90:(\tikztotarget)$) -- 
    ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztostart)$)}},
  real double straight line/.default=0.5pt, 
  one/.pic = {
    \path[clip] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
    \draw [real double straight line] (1+0.1*0.4,-0.1*0.6) to (1-1.1*0.4,1.1*0.6);
    }
  }
\path pic {one} pic[rotate=90,yscale=-1] {one};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]